# Java 8 Mvn Project doesn't work on Java 17

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a Maven Project which was written using Java 8. If I try to run it in Intelliji using SDK 17 everything is red and it doesn't work at all. If I use Java 8 however it works. Why doesn't it work with SDK 17? It should be compatible.
[Errors in my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFC4K.png)

Comment: [JavaFX is not part of the JDK anymore since java 11.](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html) Your "It should be compatible" assumption is incorrect. You need to manually add javafx to your maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Those errors are JavaFX related, not Java in general. JavaFX has never been a standard part of Java SE.

You need to either:

- **Add an implementation of JavaFX** to your project. Add dependencies to your project for the *OpenJFX* library. That code base for that implementation is housed as a subproject on the *OpenJDK* site, and is co-led by Gluon and Oracle.
- Use a **Java implementation that includes the *OpenJFX* library**. At least two vendors offer an edition of their JDK product with OpenJFX: *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems, and *LibericaFX* by BellSoft.